# на Oracle Workflow Builder таймаут уведомлении должен быть конкретным днем, а не продолжительностью

Tags: oracle

Мне нужно создать уведомление с таймаутом, но таймаут должно быть не через какое то время(где задаешь через сколько), а конкретным днем (в любой день после открытия уведомлении, таймаут должен быть следующим днем в 18:00), я попыталась создать атрибут (тип-дата) и задать этот атрибут уведомлению, но там так же не могу написать следующий день. Как мне сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Timeout может принимать атрибут типа `Date`, попробуйте.
[image: WF]

Если не работает, то используйте атрибут типа `Number` в секундах, вы можете его вычислить:

`нужная дата` - `дата отправки уведомления`